# Is it possible to get HTML and CSS output from React with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I'm not sure if this makes sense, I guess I'll see!

Essentially, let's say I have a React component. I also styled it with Styled Components. Now, I'd like to see the result. The catch is, I'm running this in `Node.js`. I'd preferably like to receive output as a string/file of a static webpage, i.e. HTML & CSS.

Take React Native as an example - it takes React code, that has Styled Components, and renders it to Android, iOS and the (static) web. I'd like to be able to render this React stuff to static files.

I *think* I need a React parser, or something along those lines. A custom implementation is fine.

Is this even possible? Am I going in over my head here? Or is the answer simpler than I imagine?

Comment: Was your react application initially created with `create-react-app`?

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand but I'll try to answer you, you can do SSR (server-side rendering) and send the html/css to your client as text. You can also do pre-rendering that generates the html/css of your app in static files I think, never used that but I think that can help you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snapshot

Comment: I never used styled-components but you have good examples of SSR for Styled-Components here: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#server-side-rendering

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky No it was not ;)

Comment: @Berthy Tried react-snapshot, not working - after going by the instructions from the npm page, I get an error: ReferenceError: navigator is not defined: I think this is because the setup is not on the server, and is using node. Will try SSR now!

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Do you simply want to generate *.html, *.css and *.js files?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky yes, that's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, [using `webpack` as a node module](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/#custom-file-systems) might help in your case. You just redirect compiler's output to a virtual (mock) file system (or you can use real FS, if that's not a concern), and then access it to get file contents:

*<sub>From the Webpack documentation:</sub>*

```js
const { createFsFromVolume, Volume } = require('memfs');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const fs = createFsFromVolume(new Volume());
const compiler = webpack({ /* configuration */ });

compiler.outputFileSystem = fs;
compiler.run((err, stats) => {
  // Read the output later:
  const content = fs.readFileSync(/* output path */);
});
```

Comment: Hi, I'm still not sure if this is what I want. If I have a file that imports React and returns a New React Component, will this be able to give me the static files for that react component? Cheers!

Comment: React by itself does not produce *.{html,js,css} files, it is a JS-only library; the asset files are actually created by Webpack. For your task you'll have to treat each component as separate React applications (having only one component), and (using Webpack) compile each application into browser-compatible assets.

Comment: Alright understandable! So just to double check, if I have React code, and with Styled Components, running it through this will output static files? Thanks!